# Android Google maps api not loading on my app

Tags: android

The error message is:

> Network error. Please try again later.

Any idea why it's possibly not loading on my phone. Everything seems to be updated and good.

Comment: if it would be good then no error should show up...

Comment: Have you got the correct permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your device has a network connection, I would assume it's because you don't have the `android.permission.INTERNET` permission declared in your manifest.